# How to remove all area around background image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a backround image which is almost black. I have filled it to the same size as the window but there is some kind of border all the way round!

HTML

```
<section id = "initialScreenContainer" class = "screenContainer">
```

CSS

```
#initialScreenContainer {
    background: url(images/bg1.png);
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.screenContainer {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see from my code I have tried to make it so that it completely covers the window, but still there is white space around it?!

Comment: It's smaller now but there is still a tiny border around it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin on the body element:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: It's smaller now but there is still a tiny border around it?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle.net example showing the exact issue?

Comment: It might be my picture. I have the second screen, as background color black instead of an image, and it is black all the way to the edge?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your background image aspect ratio doesn't match screens'. Try.:

```css
background-size: cover;
```